# VB.Net Backgroudworker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, backgroundworker, postmortem-debugging

I use Visual Studio 2013 for Visual Basic and I'm struggling to debug my multi-threaded program.

I am using a BackgroundWorker, which appears to work differently to how I think it should.

I don't understand why my program halts after processing only the first entry in my ArrayList called `arFileName`.

The `For Each` statement in BackgroundWorker1.DoWork procedure fails to iterate through the entire `arFileName` in the following code:

```
Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectCsv.Click

    'arFileName is ArrayList and it has enormous counts
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = arFileName.Count

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    'Do background
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow

    MessageBox.Show("Finished!", "info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)


End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
    Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim arNotFoundFile As New ArrayList

    'Confirm file exists
    For Each filename As String In arFileName ' Here!
        If Not IO.File.Exists(filename) Then

            arNotFoundFile.Add(filename)
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The ProgressBar will not update as it is not running on the GUI thread.  You have to enable report progress and handle the event from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backgroundworker must be set to report its progresses

```
 BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
```

Then, a typical implementation could be as follows:

```
Dim progress As Integer = 0

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    While (progress < 100)
        ' YOUR CODE HERE
        progress += 1
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ' YOUR PROGRESSBAR VALUE HERE, USING progress VARIABLE
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Work completed")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

As you can see, i've defined a **progress** variable, which will keep track of the percentage of work done. After we start the backgroundworker (which i do into the *Form_Load* event) with *RunWorkerAsync*, we could keep track of its progresses by the *ProgressChanged* event: here, we use the progress variable, modified by our work (*DoWork*). You could use it to set the progressbar value property. Finally, when all its done, we emit the message into the proper event, i.e. *RunWorkerCompleted*